# Clean column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I'm trying to clean one column which contains the ID number which is starting from S and 7 numbers, e.g.: 'S1234567' and save only this number into new column. I started with this column named Remarks, this is an example of the data inside:

```
         Remarks
0   S0252508 Shipment UK
1   S0255111 Shipment UK
2   S0256352 Shipment UK
3   S0259138 Shipment UK
4   S0260425 Shipment US
```

I've managed to separate those rows which has the format S1234567 + text using this code:

```
merged_out['Remarks'] = merged_out['Remarks'].replace("\t", "\r")
merged_out['Remarks'] = merged_out['Remarks'].replace("\n", "\r")
s = merged_out['Remarks'].str.split("\r").apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
s.name = 'Remarks'
del merged_out['Remarks']
merged_out = merged_out.join(s)
merged_out[['Number','Remarks']] = merged_out.Remarks.str.split(" ", 1, expand=True)
```

After creating a data frame I found that there are a lot of mistakes inside of that column because the data are written there manually, so there are some examples of those wrong records:

```
    Number
0. Pallets:
1. S0246734/S0246735/S0246736
3. delivery
4. S0258780 31  cok
5. S0246732-
6. 2
7. ok
8. nan
```

And this is only the wrong data which are in the Number column, I will need to clear this and save only those which has the correct number, if there is sth. like that: S0246732/S0246736/S0246738, then I need to have separated row for each number with the same data as it was for this record. For the other one I need to save those which contains the number, the other should have the null value.

Comment: Have you tried using regex?

Comment: Yes I've tried but I had more errors than using the result which I provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex approach that will do what I think your question asks:

```py
import pandas as pd
merged_out = pd.DataFrame({
'Remarks':[
'S0252508 Shipment UK',
'S0255111 Shipment UK',
'S0256352 Shipment UK',
'S0259138/S0259139 Shipment UK',
'S12345678 Shipment UK',
'S0260425 Shipment US']
})

pat = r'(?:(\bS\d{7})/)*(\bS\d{7}\b)'
df = merged_out.Remarks.str.extractall(pat)
df = ( pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(df.unstack().apply(lambda row: row.dropna().tolist(), axis=1), columns=['Number']), 
    merged_out], 
    axis=1).explode('Number') )
df.Remarks = df.Remarks.str.replace(pat + r'\s*', '', regex=True)
```

Input:

```
                          Remarks
0           S0252508 Shipment UK
1           S0255111 Shipment UK
2           S0256352 Shipment UK
3  S0259138/S0259139 Shipment UK
4          S12345678 Shipment UK
5           S0260425 Shipment US
```

Output:

```
     Number                 Remarks
0  S0252508            Shipment UK
1  S0255111            Shipment UK
2  S0256352            Shipment UK
3  S0259138            Shipment UK
3  S0259139            Shipment UK
5  S0260425            Shipment US
4       NaN  S12345678 Shipment UK
```

Explanation:

- with `Series.str.extractall()`, use a pattern to obtain 0 or more occurrences of word boundary `\b` followed by `S` followed by 7 digits and a 1 occurrence of `S` followed by 7 digits (flanked by word boundaries `\b`)
- use `unstack()` to eliminate multiple index levels
- use `apply()` with `dropna()` and `tolist()` to create a new dataframe with a `Number` column containing a list of numbers for each row
- use `explode()` to add new rows for lists with more than one `Number` item
- with `Series.str.replace()`, filter out the number matches using the previous pattern, plus `r'\s*'` to match trailing whitespace characters, to obtain the residual `Remarks`

Notes:

- all rows in the sample input contain one valid `Number` except that one row contains multiple `Number` values separated by `/` delimiters, and another row contains no valid `Number` (it has `S` followed by 8 digits, more than the 7 that make a valid `Number`)

Comment: Your solution is very good, everything works as it should, and thank you for explaining the code.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest solution is to use regular expressions and a list comprehension:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
merged_out['Remarks'] = [re.split('\s', i)[0] for i in merged_out['Remarks']]
```

Explanation:

This regular expression allows you to split the data when there is a space and makes a list from the i row in the column *Remarks*. With the 0, I selected the 0 element in this list. In this case, it is the number.

In this case, the list comprehension iterates through all the column in the dataset. In consequence, you will obtain the corresponding number of each row in the new column *Remarks*.

Comment: You forgot about left square bracket, however your solution create an error: "expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please update your answer with some code explanation? It will help others understand. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.